# How to remove user cart after order saved?django

Tags: django, django-models, save, e-commerce

I am trying to to build ecommerce website in which  user is aforeignkey to cart and cart is unique for one order,but what happens is cart is connected to all orders when trying to remove from cart it removes items from all orders  also adding to cart adds to all orders from this user what happen?i tried many solutions th separate cart and existing orders but all failed , any one can help and any suggestions for best relationships building?

```py
class Order(models.Model):
    user             = models.ForeignKey(User,null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    shipping_address = models.ForeignKey(Address, on_delete='CASCADE',related_name="shipping_address",null=True, blank=True)
    order_id         = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True)
    cart             = models.ForeignKey(Cart,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status           = models.CharField(max_length=120, default="created", choices=ORDER_STATUS_CHOISES)
    shipping_total   = models.DecimalField(default=5.00, max_digits=100, decimal_places=2)
    total            = models.DecimalField(default=0.00, max_digits=100, decimal_places=2)
    active           = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    date_posted      = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

```py
class Cart(models.Model):

    user        = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    products    = models.ManyToManyField(Product, blank=True)
    total       = models.DecimalField(default=0.00, max_digits=100, decimal_places=2)
    subtotal    = models.DecimalField(default=0.00, max_digits=100, decimal_places=2)
    updated     = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    timestamp   = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    active      = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

```py
def checkout_home(request):
    cart_obj, cart_created = Cart.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user, active=True)
    order_obj = None
    if cart_created or cart_obj.products.count() == 0:
        return redirect("carts:home")
    login_form = LoginForm()
    address_form = AddressForm()
    shipping_address_id = request.session.get("shipping_address_id", None)
    # cart_obj=request.session['cart_id']
    address_qs = None
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        address_qs = Address.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    order_obj, order_obj_created = Order.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user, status='Created',cart=cart_obj)
    if shipping_address_id:
        order_obj.shipping_address = Address.objects.get(id=shipping_address_id)
        del request.session["shipping_address_id"]
        order_obj.save()
```

Comment: You have one `Cart` per user? That seems to be your problem as all `Order`s have a foreign key to this cart which can change

Comment: user is a foreign key in cart model thats mean user may have many carts..